# R: failed to compute acf for xts object

Tags: r, xts

I have the following `xts` object as data and computing the `acf` returns the following error message.

```
> acf(data_series)
Error in round(frequency) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

The data series is as follow:

```
structure(c(23081, 22739, 22725, 22472, 22956, 22900, 22662, 
22575, 22238, 22241, 22308, 22173, 22302, 22247, 22362, 22640, 
22609, 22611, 22761, 22805, 22815, 22875), index = structure(c(1478015096.961, 
1478101498.038, 1478187898.982, 1478274298.736, 1478533498.701, 
1478619898.962, 1478706297.971, 1478792699.88, 1478879098.9, 
1479138297.291, 1479224698.879, 1479311099.631, 1479397499.52, 
1479483899.146, 1479743097.896, 1479829497.495, 1479915896.634, 
1480002297.653, 1480088688, 1480347899.956, 1480434296.234, 1480520699.948
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .Dim = c(22L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Close"))
```

Now, I am puzzled as to why this did not work because these are daily data. Can someone help me out on this please?

Comment: As is says in the help file: the class should be numeric or an ACF object. (x: a univariate or multivariate (not ccf) numeric time series object or a numeric vector or matrix, or an "acf" object)

Comment: my data is already `double`. Would this not work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
acf(coredata(data_series))
```

Explanation:  Your data series is an `xts` object, not of type numeric vector or matrix.  That's why you're getting an error, even though the underlying data is really numeric.  `coredata()` applied to an `xts` object returns the underlying (usually numeric type) matrix.

```
> class(data_series)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

> class(coredata(data_series))
[1] "matrix"
```